# Rate of change problem (Differential Calculus)

Tags: calculus

**Problem:** An object moves along a straight line such that, after t minutes, its distance from its starting point $D = \frac{20t + 5}{(t+1)}$ meters. At what speed, in m/minutes will it be moving at the end of 4 minutes?

**Attempt:** $D = \frac{20t + 5}{(t+1)}$,
$\frac{dD}{dt} =$ $\frac{(t+1)(20)-(20t+5)(1)}{(t+1)^2}$ =$\frac{15}{(t + 1)^2}$ and substituting t = 4 will result to **0.6 m / minutes**. I have done the differentiation through 2 formulas ($d(uv)$ and $d(\frac{u}{v}))$ and also through calculator techniques, and the answer all results to **0.6**.

**Problem:** But 0.6 is wrong as the answer should be **19.8**. What part did I get wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Edit the question to show us your work and we may be able to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker There, I showed the manual solution in getting the 0.6. I didn't show the other solution such as the calculator shortcut method as they are done only for checking.

Comment: could the answer given to you be wrong? because what you've done seems correct

Comment: @TheIntegrator that's what I'm thinking

Comment: @TheIntegrator The book shows the differentiation should be : $\frac{dD}{dt}$ = $20 - \frac{5}{(t + 1)^2}$ which when t = 4, answer is 19.8. But I don't know how did he arrived with that solution.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it has something to do with conversion of units or differentiate with respect to something I don't know.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the case $t$ is in minutes and $D$  in meters, and $\dfrac{dD}{dt} $ in meter per  minute, so the units all check out

Comment: For the given problem their solution isn't correct. Your solution is correct.

Comment: @TheIntegrator Actually, it is a multiple choice question. Wherein the choices are: 19.8 , 29.9, 39.8 and 49.8. Answer key and solution tells the correct answer is 19.8

Comment: Also the differentiation that they've done is wrong. you could integrate it to check it. It  does not match the equation of $D$ in the slightest way.  You're book might be wrong. I suggest you verify it with your teacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation must  be $D=20t+\frac5{t+1}$ and not $\frac {20t+5}{t+1}$ so when you differentiate w.r.t it will give $\frac {dD}{dt}=20-\frac5{(t+1)^2}$ so putting t=4 results  $\frac {dD}{dt}=20-\frac 5{(4+1)^2}=20-\frac 5{25}=19.8 m/min$

Comment: Dang! I didn't realized that!!!

Comment: no problem .It happens :)

Comment: +1 for the reverse engineering.

Comment: thanks,yup integrating equation